# AIML 2.0 not supported JAVA

Tags: html, bots, aiml

Hello so I've been using this version of program ab :

> ```
>     < dependency >
>         < groupId>org.goldrenard</groupId >
>         < artifactId>ab</artifactId >
>         < version>1.0.7</version >
>     < /dependency >
> ```

And I've been havin some issues lately with it : I can not use tags such as < link > < img >,..

Anyone has already had this problem or know another library to download a compatible version of program ab with aiml 2.0 ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I use this link to download Program AB: https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/

Comment: If I may ask, once downloaded u add the whole folder manually as a library ?

Comment: No need to add anything else. Program AB is a stand alone interpreter.